# How big is the difference between C0 Yae Miko and C2 Yae Miko?

Tags: genshin-impact

Yae Miko's 2nd Constellation reads:

> Sesshou Sakura start at Level 2 when created, their max level is increased to 4, and its attack range is increased by 60%

What I'm more interested is how much of a range boost the 60% equates to.  Since we don't have access to actual values for the base turret range, how much is 60% doing for her Sesshou Sakura turrets?

Comment: _"Since we don't have access to actual values"_ - 100% -> 160%. As we don't have actual values, what answer do you expect? Would actual values like 140 to 224 units help? The turrets reach 60% farther.

Comment: Please note that radius of a circle is πr², meaning that a 60% increase of the radius (1.6) with be 1.6² = 2.56, which is a 156% increase of the area of effect of the spell.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica What's 100%? How do I reference what 100% is so I can understand what 160% looks like?  Imagine going shopping and the store never lists the prices of items, only the discount % applied, so all you see is "this product is 20% off" but you have no way to gauge what 100% is even to see if the discount is even worth it.  If say the base range of the turrets is 10 units, then a 60% increase in range doesn't seem worth it for a second constellation. But if say the range was 30 units, then a 60% increase would be absolutely huge.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica to be fair, childe question here seems quite clear. The point is not the percentage of the increase, but to compare that to some know element in the game in order to understand how much coverage it provides. Like they said, the game does not provide a numeric value for the base range, so every calculation has to be done empirically or by datamining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best I could found is some data from the 2.5 beta tests.

During the tests, [someone on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact_Leaks/comments/ryrnlp/yaes_aoe_compared_to_the_spiral_abyss/) posted the following diagrams:

[image]
Base coverage provided by three totems compared to the Abyss floor size. The red area should be the totem linking range (does not increase), while the blue area is the attack range. Basically, this means that at least in the beta, the totems had a 10 meters range - the size of Albedo E skill field.

[image]
This was what C2 was said to look like. Note that the range increased from 10 to 20.

I did some more research and found out that at the same time...
[image]
leaks reported a 100% range increase for totem range a C2. So, the diagram picture is consistent with the range increase C2 provided during the beta.

Since in the final release the increase is just 60% that means that the final range should be 16 units assuming the base range is still 10 meters (seems the case based on comments on the Yae subreddit)

Answer (score 1):

From [WintrySnowman's Reddit guide:](https://v.redd.it/3a0hxp3w1ui81)

[image]